# How to transfer Azure VMs from one expressroute circuit to another?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have following environment set-up

- Cloud: Microsoft **Azure**
- **Expressroute** circuit (Circuit 1) configured to extend on-premise to Azure (site to site)
- Expressroute circuit (Circuit 1) has one vNet (**Virtual Network - ABCNetwork**)
- Virtual Network (ABCNetwork ) has one subnet with IP Range and VMs are created in this subnet.

The initial allocated address range is smaller! so we can not add any more VMs. So we thought to create new circuit with larger IP range. This circuit is entitled as **Circuit-2**

**Problem**: Now we have to move all the VMs from one circuit to other!!

But not sure about steps :(  I think we have to keep the disks in backup and then re-create the VMs in new circuit. but I am looking for standard steps.

This link shows that we can link the vNet to ciruit.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/expressroute-howto-linkvnet-classic/ but not sure if I can link the vNet which already have the VMs in it.

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: How can I migrate this question to ServerFault?